# M2 MacBook Pro cannot scan BLE devices

Tags: bluetooth, scanning

I have some devices BLE (based on ESP32-S3) that do not appear on the bluetooth scan list of my M2 MacBook Pro but I can see them using a PC. This is my MacBook bluetooth system report:

```
Bluetooth Controller:
  Address:  XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
  State:    On
  Chipset:  BCM_4388
  Discoverable: Off
  Firmware Version: 20.7.324.2713
  Product ID:   0x4A11
  Supported Devices:    0x382039 < HFP AVRCP A2DP HID Braille AACP GATT SerialPort >
  Transport:    PCIe
  Vendor ID:    0x004C (Apple)
```

Does MacBook support BLE?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the M2 MacBooks all support BLE.

Please note that even thought the name "Bluetooth" and "Bluetooth Low Energy" are similar - it is actually completely separate protocols.

You cannot use Bluetooth to find BLE devices. It doesn't work that way.

Try using a dedicated BLE scanner app, such as for example [BLEScanner](https://apps.apple.com/de/app/simple-ble-scanner/id1663446245?l=en).